# How to write data to Apache Iceberg tables using Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-iceberg

I am trying to familiarize myself with Apache Iceberg and I'm having some trouble understanding how to write some external data to a table using Spark SQL.

- I have a file, *one.csv*, sitting in a directory, */data*
- my Iceberg catalog is configured to point to this directory, */warehouse*
- I want to write this *one.csv* to an Apache Iceberg table (preferably using Spark SQL)

Is it even possible to read external data using Spark SQL? And then write it to the iceberg tables? Do I have to use scala or python to do this? I've been through the Iceberg and Spark 3.0.1 documentation a bunch but maybe I'm missing something.

**Code Update**

Here is some code that I hope will help

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type", "hive")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.local", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.local.type", "hadoop")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.local.warehouse", "data/warehouse")
```

I have the data I need to use sitting in a directory */one/one.csv*

How do I get it into an Iceberg table using Spark? Can all of this be done purely using SparkSQL?

```
spark.sql(
"""
CREATE or REPLACE TABLE local.db.one
USING iceberg
AS SELECT * FROM `/one/one.csv`
"""
)
```

Then the goal is I can work with this iceberg table directly for example:

```
select * from local.db.one
```

and this would give me all the content from the */one/one.csv* file.

Comment: how to write to a table is documented or not? https://iceberg.apache.org/getting-started/ - so you should be able to load the CSV to a Spark Dataframe and insert this into a Iceberg table - what exactly does not work? You should show code sample

Comment: @UninformedUser I added some code to clarify, hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 3):

To use the SparkSQL, read the file into a dataframe, then register it as a temp view. This temp view can now be referred in the SQL as:

```
var df = spark.read.format("csv").load("/data/one.csv")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tempview");

spark.sql("CREATE or REPLACE TABLE local.db.one USING iceberg AS SELECT * FROM tempview");
```

To answer your other question, Scala or Python is not required; the above example is in Java.

Comment: note that if you're going to overwrite, the temp view and the sql are not needed, the java api can also do that

Answer (score 0):

This example is reading data from Kafka and writing data to Iceberg table

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions")
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog")
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type", "hive")
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.catalog.hive_catalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog")
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.catalog.hive_catalog.type", "hadoop")
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.catalog.hive_catalog.warehouse", "hdfs://host:port/user/hive/warehouse")
sparkConf.set("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://host:19083")
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.catalog.hive_prod", " org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog")
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.catalog.hive_prod.type", "hive")
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.catalog.hive_prod.uri", "thrift://host:19083")
sparkConf.set("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://host:port/user/hive/warehouse")
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .config(sparkConf)
  .master("yarn")
  .appName("kafkaTableTest")
  .getOrCreate()

spark.sql(
  """
    |
    |create table if not exists hive_catalog.icebergdb.kafkatest1(
    |    company_id int,
    |    event string,
    |    event_time timestamp,
    |    position_id int,
    |    user_id int
    |)using iceberg
    |PARTITIONED BY (days(event_time))
    |""".stripMargin)

import spark.implicits._



val df: DataFrame = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka_server")
  .option("subscribe", "topic")
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .load()
//.selectExpr("cast (value as string)")

val value: DataFrame = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[String]
  .map(data => {
    val json_str: JSONObject = JSON.parseObject(data)
    val company_id: Integer = json_str.getInteger("company_id")
    val event: String = json_str.getString("event")
    val event_time: String = json_str.getString("event_time")
    val position_id: Integer = json_str.getInteger("position_id")
    val user_id: Integer = json_str.getInteger("user_id")
    (company_id, event, event_time, position_id, user_id)
  })
  .toDF("company_id", "event", "event_time", "position_id", "user_id")



value.createOrReplaceTempView("table")

spark.sql(
  """
    |select
    | company_id,
    | event,
    | to_timestamp(event_time,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as event_time,
    | position_id,
    | user_id
    |from table
    |""".stripMargin)
  .writeStream
  .format("iceberg")
  .outputMode("append")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
  .option("path","hive_catalog.icebergdb.kafkatest1") // tablePath: catalog.db.tableName
  .option("checkpointLocation","hdfspath")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```